# jQuery - Post Form Loaded from another page using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, ajaxform

I am trying to use JQuery to submit a form without reloading the page.  Although this works well with the jQuery Form Plugin on a standalone page I need it to work on a page I've loaded with AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('#LoadForm').click(function() {
    $('#formDiv1').load('FormGen.asp');
  });
</script>
```

When I click submit on the loaded form however, the form submits and refreshes the page instead of submitting with just AJAX.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
   $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
      alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
   }); 
 }); 
</script>
```

If I put the code in the page I call and use that standalone it works perfect.  It doesn't however work when I am attempting to load the form from another page.

Comment: I think your problem is that $(document).ready will never be executed for the page loaded dynamically. You could try adding the code contained on that method at the end of the page, but without any event handler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the `on()` method to bind to things being loaded by AJAX - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: to bind... events, not for initializing a plugin instance on elements added via ajax. Not only this answer is lacking content but I really wonder it can solve the exposed problem.

Answer (score 2):

When your page load, the element `#myForm` **does not exist yet** in the page (because you load with ajax) so the `ajaxForm()` plugin is not initialized.

You should initialize it when your ajax content has successfully loaded. To do so, use the callback parameter of the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method that is executed when the loading has occurred:

```
$('#formDiv1').load('FormGen.asp', function(data, status, xhr) {

    // this is executed when the load has finished
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

eerrrr... my bad, didn't correctly read the quesion - Didier Ghys's answer seems more appropriate.

---

`click()` binds an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event. The binding is done when the script is executed.

Since you laod tour form by ajax, I suppose the `click()` function is called before the form is loaded, and thus there is no binding.

Try using the [`live()` function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) :

```
  $('#LoadForm').live("click", function() {
     $('#formDiv1').load('FormGen.asp');
  });
```